# Count of a Range

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I, more or less, want to make a histogram of a table of percentages.  At the moment, I'm coding it up like this:

```
Sum(
    Case
         When
              PROP.Proportion <= 0.05
         Then
              1
     End
    ) as "0.05"
```

I worry that a series of those going up to 100% will perform poorly.  Is there a better way to do it?  Something like:

Count(PROP.Proportion <= 0.05)?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't bother about the cost of a CASE expression. That is pretty small compared to all the other work.

Comment: @anonimitie . . . Your code is fine.